# check to see if public sting Label =" ": empty or not c#

Tags: c#

check to see if public sting Label =" ": empty or not
c#

i have

```
[DataField("label")] public string Label = "";
```

and i need check if it empty or not

Comment: What prevents you?

Comment: `if (Label == string.Empty)`?

Comment: What's wrong with `Label == string.Empty` or even `Label == ""`.

Comment: @PeterSmith  `string.Empty` has a capital `E`  ...

Comment: @derpirscher Typo now corrected. Thanks

Comment: There's also if (`Label.IsNullOrEmpty())`

Answer (score 1):

A good practice for strings is to use string methods :

```cs
string.IsNullOrEmpty(label); // => true on null or empty string
// or
string.IsNullOrWhitespace(label); // => true on null, empty string or only containing whitespaces
```